# Create multiple word count lists from a Pandas Dataframe and export to multiple excel sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, nltk

Hoping someone can help me with this. I am running K-Means clustering on some text data. After I get the different cluster groups in my pandas dataframe, I then want to create a word count list for text in the "Processed_Data" column for each of the cluster groups the model put into my dataframe. After it creates each list I want them exported to individual excel worksheets within one excel file. For this particular code I had 17 clusters and want 17 word count lists exported into 17 worksheets of one file.

I have separately been able to export the data of each cluster into their own sheets and create word count list for individual clusters, but have had no success doing both while looping through each cluster group.

Example data:

```
|SN |Processed_Data                 |cluster    |
-------------------------------------------------
|123|hello world good bye world     |    01     |
|111|hello world                    |    01     |
|222|good bye world                 |    02     |
|555|world great                    |    02     |
|543|an african or european swallow?|    03     |
|777|what do you mean?              |    03     |
```

Results I want put into individual excel sheets base on the cluster number:

```
cluster 01:
| word | freq|
---------------
|world |  3  |
|hello |  2  |
|good  |  1  |
|bye   |  1  |

cluster 02: 
| word | freq|
--------------
|world |  2  |
|great |  1  |
|good  |  1  |
|bye   |  1  |

ect for each cluster...
```

Here is the code I tried but it does not seem to work for me. I am not showing all the preprocessing code like removing capitalization, stopwords, and punctuation because I did not have any issues with that and it added length to the post.

```py
true_k = 17
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=15)
model.fit(X)
labels=model.labels_
data_clusters=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(df['SN'],df['Processed_Data'],labels)),columns=['SN','Processed_Data','cluster'])
data_clusters = data_clusters.sort_values(by=['cluster'])
data_clusters['cluster'] = data_clusters['cluster'].astype(str)

uniques = data_clusters['cluster'].unique()

with pd.ExcelWriter('cluster_test.xlsx') as writer:
    for cluster in uniques:
        a = data_clusters.loc[data_clusters['cluster'] == cluster][['Processed_Data']].str.cat(sep=' ')
        words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
        word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
        rslt = dict((word, freq) for word, freq in word_dist.items() if not word.isdigit())
        rslt = pd.DataFrame(list(word_dist.items()),
                            columns =['Word', 'Freq'])
        rslt = rslt.sort_values(by=['Freq'], ascending=False)
        rslt['Cluster'] = cluster
        rslt.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=cluster)
```

Just a bit of a heads up, I had to change the clustering column into a string using `data_clusters['cluster'] = data_clusters['cluster'].astype(str)`
so the Excel writer could name the sheets after the cluster numbers. It had problems using the integers to name the sheets. Wondering if this might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
import openpyxl
df = pd.DataFrame(
   {
  'SN': [123,111,222,555,543,777],
  'Processed_Data':   ['hello world good bye world','hello world', 'good bye world','world great','an african or european swallow?','what do you mean?'],
  'cluster' : ['01','01','02','02','03','03']
   
 })

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("cluster")["Processed_Data"]) 

wb = openpyxl.Workbook('Cluster.xlsx') 
wb.save('Cluster.xlsx') #Create an excel file

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    print(index)
    temp_list = row[1].str.split(' ').tolist()
    flat_temp_list = [item for sublist in temp_list for item in sublist]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'words': flat_temp_list })   
    temp_df = temp_df.groupby(["words"])["words"].count().reset_index(name="freq")
    with pd.ExcelWriter('Cluster.xlsx',engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
        temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet'+str(index))
```

Your excel sheets look like:

```
words    freq
0   bye     1
1   good    1
2   hello   2
3   world   3

words     freq
0   bye     1
1   good    1
2   great   1
3   world   2

words       freq
0   african   1
1   an        1
2   do        1
3   european. 1
4   mean?     1
5   or        1
6   swallow?  1
7   what      1
8   you       1
```

Comment: Thank you! Was able to take what you did and solve it. Needed each of them to go into the same excel file but different worksheets within that file. Just changed some things up a bit. Edited my questions to show the answer.

Comment: You mean same excel and different worksheets? If so I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from **Inputvector** I was able to solve this. I took their code and just moved some thing around so it exported into individual worksheets of one excel file.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_clusters.groupby("cluster")["Processed_Data"]) 

with pd.ExcelWriter('cluster_test_4.xlsx') as writer:
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        temp_list = row[1].str.split(' ').tolist()
        flat_temp_list = [item for sublist in temp_list for item in sublist]
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'words': flat_temp_list })   
        temp_df = temp_df.groupby(["words"])["words"].count().reset_index(name="freq")
        temp_df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=str(index))
```